# How do I encapsulate third-party JavaScript files so they don't pollute the global scope?

Tags: javascript

One of my clients is asking if they can add some JavaScript to track user behavior to their website. At first glance I fear that it is going to interfere with other third-party analytics scripts on the site because it looks like both parties have used the same JavaScript compressor. I don't want to comb through and search for every possible naming collision so . . .

Is there a way I can include third-party scripts (script files which live on a separate domain) but wrap them in their own namespace or give them their own scope so they don't collide with other globally declared variables and functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should not be a problem. Javascript compressors do not rename global variables (for obvious reasons), and any well-designed script will not expose many (any) globals. If they want you to deploy it on your page, it is their responsibility to prevent clashes.

Comment: I like your point about how it's their responsibility to prevent crashes. That gives me some ammo when I go back to my client.

Answer (score 5):

In order of isolation:

1. An (i)frame hosted on a different domain - no direct interactions possible
2. An (i)frame hosted on the same domain - interactions only possible via explicit window/frame references
3. A self-executing anonymous function - interactions are simple but well-behaved code can be isolated
4. None - hope no one uses the same variable or function names

It would depend on the third-party script but I generally lean towards #2.  Interactions are possible but you're insulated from casual document.write use and global namespace pollution.

Edit: Example of #2

in page.html

```
<div>...Your content...</div>
<iframe src="tracker.html" 
    width="10" height="10" 
    style="position:absolute; top:-100px"></iframe>
```

tracker.html (optionally the whole thing)

```
<script src="http://example.com/tracker.js"></script>
```

That's the basic structure but needs a little more setup or else all traffic would appear to be coming from tracker.html.  For a tracking script I suggest providing the top (real) page's path in the query string to the iframe: "tracker.html?u=thispage.html".  You could setup the query string either server side or via javascript:

page.html (again)

```
<div>...Your content...</div>
<script>
    (function(){
        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.src = 'tracker.html?u=' + escape(location.href);
        iframe.width = iframe.height = 1;
        iframe.style.position = 'absolute';
        iframe.style.top = '-100px';

        var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
        var s = nodes[nodes.length - 1];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(iframe, s);

    })();
</script>
```

You could optionally just use location.pathname rather than location.href (which has protocol, domain, etc.) if the path is enough for your tracking.

After all that... if the tracking script is from a reputable source ([StatCounter](http://www.statcounter.com/), [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/), etc.) I suggest trusting them to not step on your pages variables and functions.  Options 1 and 2 are really for low trust situations.

Comment: Could you elaborate on option #2 for me? Do you have links to articles or examples where that technique is used?

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
(function() {
    // insert code here
})();
```

Enjoy ;)

Comment: Be aware that if your client doesn't use *var* do declare variables, they will end up in the global scope.

Comment: or if they manually add them to a global namespace (window.* = 123;)

Comment: By third party I meant that they want me to add a `<script src="http://notmydomain.com/somescript.js">` tag to each of my page layouts.

Comment: Ah, well in the case you probably wouldn't be able to affect it unless you ask the third party nicely. Third party scripts should be made to not pollute the global scope anyway, but not everyone is rigorous about that...

Comment: @Timmy – Can't you really copy-paste the script into your own file and wrap it around with that self-executing anonymous function? Be aware that other domains may be slower or even unavailable, which may lead to unexpected results/behaviour when a third party script isn't loaded at all.

Comment: @Marcel - The scripts really should remain editable by the script owners. I'm really at their whim if they want to change how their analytics script works.

Answer (score 1):

It depends of what you want to do exactly.

***1) You want to load the third party scripts in your pages in a way that your sure it wont break your scripts.***

You can't do a lot here.
Ask the third party to do clean scripts.... not really possible in general
Load the script in an iframe.... probably will make the script useless

There's maybe a way, but it's probably stupid :
load the script via ajax (may need a proxy to avoid cross domain), create a JS function with the content of the script (`new Function('The content of the script');`), and then execute the function (you can also use eval... it's the same).
This way, you can manage arguments you give to the function, and this way you can protect global variables for example.
Doing this is probably a good way to break the third party script. Will it protect yours ?... maybe.

Anyway, you should also protect you from third party script unavailable. Whenever you try to use a variable declared in a third party script, always check if the variable is defined to be sure the script is loaded.

***2) You want to code your scripts a way it won't be broken by any third party scripts***

First : global variables are dangerous.
You don't know who made them, you don't know who modified them... don't trust them.

There's one variable you can trust : the this keyword in the global scope. It should be the window object, and this object should be protected a little (should be a constant at least).

If you have to create arrays, strings, regExp... try not to use the "`new Something()`" way to do it

```
var myArray = []; // not new Array();
var myRegExp = /^myRegExp$/; // not new RegExp('^myRegExp$');
var myString = 'myString'; // not new String('myString');
```

For example, the Array variable can be overwritten. If you use [], you won't mind.

There's cases where you can't do another way of course, but try not to.

As you can't trust global variables, you should also avoid create some. Create only the absolutely necessary global variables. everything else should be local. If your script are less intrusives, other will maybe try to do the same.

To do this (use mainly local variables), you should work in a "protected area". a good way to do this is an anonymous self-executing function.

```
(function () {
    // Your code here
}());
```

You can also pass global variables to this "base function". This can be good for minification, and for protection. You can also get an "undefined" variable to be the reference to check if variables are defined or not.

```
(function (window, alert, Array, undef) {
    // Your code here
    alert('I\'m safe here.');

    if([] instanceof Array) {
        alert('I\'ve got the real Array object');
    }

    if(window.jQuery === undef) {
        alert('jQuery not loaded');
    }

}(this, this.alert, this.Array));
```

I think this way your script should be a little bit protected. There's probably other things I forgot, but this is a good start.